# How can you fix the height of an element in IE 6, and allow hidden content to be scrolled into view?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

IE 6 treats the CSS `height` property as if it were `min-height`, i.e. if an element has `height: 500px` applied to it, but its contents are taller than 500px, the element will get taller to accommodate them.

I'm trying to give an element a fixed height, and add a scrollbar to allow the contents to be scrolled into view if necessary.

How can I make IE 6 honour the `height` assigned to it, and allow content to be scrolled into view?

`.myelement {height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;}` works in other browsers, but not IE 6.

Comment: I remember having a workaround for overflowing width hidden somewhere on my hard drive but I'm not sure about height...

Comment: Also in before "IE6 is dead stop supporting it" babble...

Comment: Actually, your code should work in IE6. It only treats `height` and `width` like their min counterparts when a box has `overflow: visible`. Can you set up a test case?

Comment: @BoltClock: huh, you're quite right - `overflow-y:scroll` works fine in a minimal test case: http://jsfiddle.net/uqqPw/1/. I must have something else going on in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-y:scroll;` should work on IE6 as well.

```
<div id='test' style="position:absolute; top:10px;left:50px; width:500px; height:200px;background-color: #ffffff; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div  style="position: absolute; top: 10px; height: 650px; left: 50px; width: 500px;background-color: #000000;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're quite right, it does - sorry, I must have something else going on in my code. (That'll teach me to get a test case up before posting my question.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I've tested it in IE6:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmq3r/

Simply set a height and give it overflow:auto